# Error Code: 1292 Truncated incorrect CHAR(8) value: '20160331000000'

Tags: mysql

i am trying to get a date from `subtracting` `interval of 1 day` from a date 
and stored concating this with `P` in a `variable` temp_new_date_name that's `datatype` is `varchar(256)`
in stored procedure.
and `new_date` is `datetime` datatype.

During debug i found that `new_Date` value is `'2016-04-01 00:00:00'`

```
set temp_new_date_name =concat('p',CAST(((new_date - INTERVAL 1 DAY)+0) as char(8)));
```

Then i got following error

```
Error Code: 1292 Truncated incorrect CHAR(8) value: '20160331000000'
```

while i have tried following on my local,Then its working fine

```
select concat('p',  CAST((('2016-04-01 00:00:00' - INTERVAL 1 DAY)+0) as char(8)));
```

i have tried google ,but didn't find any working solution.
Your help is appreciable.
Thanks

Let me know if you want more detail regarding this question

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this answer by increasing the size of char(8) to char(20).